# Получить текст из изображения PHP

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно реализовать извлечение текста из картинок(png, jpg). Как на сервисе https://img2txt.com. Нужно получать текст из скана паспортов. Копал в сторону библиотек, нашел PHP OCR, но в ней особо не удалось разобраться. Решил попробовать написать сам, застопорился, не совсем понятен алгоритм. Сделал изображение черно белым для удобства получения текста, но вот вопрос что дальше? Нужно вырезать темные пиксели и из них составить текст?

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatefrompng('scan.png');

function updateImage($im, $contrast = -1500) {
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,$contrast);
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im)-2, imagesy($im)-2);
    imagecopy($output, $im, 0, 0, 1, 1, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

    imagefilter($output, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
    return $im = $output;
    
}

updateImage($im);

imagepng($im, 'new_img3.png');
```

Comment: Гуглим. Читаем - https://habr.com/ru/post/220077/

Comment: ну да, написать распознавание текста самому ведь куда проще. чем научиться работать с библиотекой.